# If and return in Nodejs or Java

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this example code

```
var randFriend = friendList[Math.floor(Math.random() * friendList.length)];
if (randFriend == admin) {
    //Here
}
else if (randFriend != admin) {
    client.removeFriend(randFriend);
}
```

How can I do if `if randfriend == admin` to do again `var randFriend = friendList[Math.floor(Math.random() * friendList.length)];` and check `if(randFriend == admin)` again. In other words, to restart that again.

I think that it's done with return, but I don't know. Thanks

Comment: `do { randFriend = /* pick random */; } while (randFriend == admin);`

Comment: `java != javascript`

Comment: Use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on your `friendList` to get a list containg only elements that are not equal to `admin` and pick a random entry out of that filtered list.

Comment: It's this good? Thanks to all.                                                                      [code]do { var randFriend = friendList[Math.floor(Math.random() * friendList.length)]; } while (randFriend == admin);
client.removeFriend(randFriend);[/code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you could use a while loop to keep randomizing until an admin isn't selected

```
var friendAdmin = true;
var randFriend;
while(friendAdmin){
   randFriend = friendList[Math.floor(Math.random() * friendList.length)];
   if(randFriend != admin) friendAdmin = false;
}
client.removeFriend(randFriend);
```

Comment: Andy Turner's comment may be more concise than this one but it achieves the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use recursion or loops with random conditions, because you will have problems to estimate the runtime, and if the use case changes and you would have more elements you want to ignore, then the probability to find the correct element will decrease.

A better idea would be to filter the array to remove the elements you want to ignore and then pick a random element from that list.

```
var nonAdminList = friendList.filter(person => person != admin);

if( nonAdminList.length === 0 ) {
  throw new Error('no non admin persons available');
}

client.removeFriend(nonAdminList[Math.floor(Math.random() * nonAdminList.length)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put your code into a function so that you can invoke the function again if you want to repeat it. For example:

```
function choose(){
        var randFriend = friendList[Math.floor(Math.random() * friendList.length)];
        if(randFriend == admin){
            choose(); //this repeats the choose function, which will run the random friend code again
        }
        else if(randFriend != admin){
            client.removeFriend(randFriend);
            return; //this exits the function
        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use recursion for such a task. In this particular example it might not be a problem, but still not a good solution.

Comment: Why not? Especially if this function gets more complex, it may be reduce the complexity of looping to re run conditionals. I understand that it can be expensive setting up a new stack frame, but at a certain point this method can be useful and easy to understand.

Comment: If the use case changes and more elements would meet the condition that they should be ignored then it will become more likely the you get a stackoverflow at some point. This is for sure always true for recursion, but recursion with a random condition is never a good idea because you will never know the actual runtime. A similar problem is with while. Filtering is IMHO the only good solution.